# Informix - Insert a boolean attribute

Tags: insert, informix

I have this table definition :

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios
 (
  CI  INT PRIMARY KEY,
  primer_nombre   varchar(25) NOT NULL CHECK (primer_nombre MATCHES '^[a-zA-Z]$' ),
  segundo_nombre   varchar(25),
  primer_apellido   varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  segundo_apellido   varchar(25),
  grado INT CHECK ( grado > 0 AND grado < 8),
  fecha_nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
  nota INT CHECK ( nota > 0 AND nota < 13),
  email varchar(80),
  hace_proyecto boolean,
  tipo varchar(20) CHECK (tipo IN ('Admin', 'Docente', 'Alumno')),
  encriptacion_hash varchar(250),
  encriptacion_sal varchar(250),
  baja boolean 
 );
```

And this insert statement :

```
INSERT INTO Usuarios (CI, primer_nombre,segundo_nombre,primer_apellido,segundo_apellido,grado,fecha_nacimiento,nota,email,hace_proyecto,tipo,encriptacion_hash,encriptacion_sal,baja)
VALUES (
        999999,
        "Gabriel"
        "Matias",
        "Barrios",
        "Cabrera",
        NULL,
        "10/28/1986",
        1,
        "myemail@gmail.com"
        true,
        "Alumno",
        NULL,
        NULL,
        false
        );
```

No matter what I do, I always get :

```
Connected.


  201: A syntax error has occurred.
Error in line 17
Near character position 8

Disconnected.
```

I think it is related to my boolean fields. Is this true? How can I insert a boolean into my table ?

Comment: The constraint check that is failing is the MATCHES on `primo_nombre`.  MATCHES is not a full regular expression; it is more like a limited Bourne shell globbing mechanism.  Neither `^` nor `$` has a special meaning, and there is no 'repeat previous pattern' option either.  Using `"^G$"` in place of `"Gabriel"`, an insert was successful (with DBDATE set to MDY4/ — or unset — to support the shown date format).

Comment: oh ok. One question @JonathanLeffler, Is it possible to name the constraint somehow? So I have a clearer message when one fails?

Comment: Yes.  For example: `…  grado INT CHECK ( grado > 0 AND grado < 8) CONSTRAINT usuarios_grado, …`.  The name comes after the constraint in Informix; in standard SQL, it comes before.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @JonathanLeffler I was trying to place it before the condition as in SQL. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing a ',' after "Gabriel" and then again after "myemail@gmail.com", and lastly the booleans are inserted as `'t'` or `'f'` I believe.

Once I made those changes I just get an error about one of the check constraint's failing.

Comment: Thanks so much. Additionally I had to make the VALUES clause a single line also, it seems Informix did not like my spacing a lot. Anyway, I understand I have constraint.  I might have to name them I guess because the error code its not very verbose :  530: Check constraint (admin_proyecto.c105_35) failed.

Comment: @MatiasBarrios: Informix doesn't care how many lines your VALUES clause is split over.  It does require the white space to be insignificant, though.  (There is a mechanism for getting newlines into literal strings if you need it; that isn't really an issue here.)